# Django - setting CSRF token on API view

Tags: python, django, api, csrf-token

I'm creating a API endpoint to receive data and create model objects out of said data.  I've currently got two views for this API - one that sends the data and one that receives it - but in reality, I'll be using a script to send the data instead of a view.  I'm working on the view to receive data on my local host which is why I've got the one that sends it for now.

The current issue I'm facing is with the function that sends the data to the API endpoint.  My POST request is coming back with a 403 error and it says `Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /reports/swipe/data`.  To fix this I'm trying to add a CSRF cookie, but I'm very new to API endpoints and have had some trouble with it.  I've tried using `@csrf_exempt` and adding `verify=False` among other things, but I haven't had any success yet.  I've also spent a few hours searching online for resources that could help.  Below is portions of my code.  I'd appreciate whatever suggestions people can provide.

views.py:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date, time
import time
import datetime
import json
import os
from django.shortcuts import render
from swipe.models import MyModel
import requests
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.http import HttpResponse


def receive_data(request):
        """
        we need the primary keys of the id rows in case they send us the same data twice
        or we don't even run it and need to run it on new data every time

        get primary key of each row in the original query to have that sent to us as well
        create --> update | create
        """

        if request.method == 'POST':
            bb_data = request.POST.get('data', '')

            for entry in bb_data:
                print(entry)
                new_swipe = MyModel.objects.create(
                    eventtransactions_id= int(entry['eventtransactions_id']),
                    customer_lastname= entry['customer_lastname'],
                    customer_firstname= entry['customer_firstname'],
                    birthdate= datetime.datetime.strptime(entry['birthdate'], '%m-%d-%Y'),
                    customer_gender= entry['customer_gender'],
                )
                print("ENTRY CREATED") #for testing
@csrf_exempt
def send_data(request):

    API_ENDPOINT = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_api"

    for x in range(3):
        bb_dict = {
            'eventtransactions_id': 0000111,
            'customer_gender': 'F',
            'customer_firstname': 'Jan',
            'customer_lastname': 'Smith',
            'birthdate': datetime.datetime(2000, 2, 10, 10, 23, 40, 123443),
            }

    json_bb_dict = json.dumps(bb_dict, default=str)
    requests.post(API_ENDPOINT, data=json_bb_dict, verify=False)
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from swipe.views import receive_data, send_data

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^data', receive_data, name='data_import'),
    url(r'^test', send_data, name='data_export'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You've added @csrf_exempt decorator to send_data function but your error text mentions */reports/swipe/data* url, which leads to receive_data function. Consider adding @csrf_exempt to receive_data function (assuming you don't care about csrf injections)